# creating a drop down menu function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a little problem with my drop menu function. what i want to have is that after clicking a menu tab for the second time it visibility should be hidden.

here is my code....

HTML:-

```
<nav class="clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li class="navTab marginRight">
            <a><span class="iconFont">v</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a></a></li>
                <li><a></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navTab marginRight">
            <a><span class="iconFont">v</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a></a></li>
                <li><a></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navTab">
            <a><span class="iconFont">v</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a></a></li>
                <li><a></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:-

```
.navTab ul.visible {
  visibility: visible;
}

.navTab ul {
  display: inline;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 200;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;  
}
```

jQuery:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var list = $('.navTab ul'); 

  $('li.navTab').click(function(){
    var thatIndex = $(this).index();
    list.not( ':eq(thatIndex)' ).removeClass('visible');
    list.eq(thatIndex).addClass('visible');
  });
});
```

Comment: `list.not( ':eq(' + thatIndex +')' ).removeClass('visible');` JS variable should be used properly, as of now you are using it as string

Comment: thanks, but what i want as an example is if i click the first list it will show the hidden content, clicking it twice should hide the content

Comment: here if u click the first li and then click the second li, first li content will be hidden and the second li content will be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i think you are looking for this.?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('li.navTab ul').hide();  
  $('li.navTab').click(function(){   
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();  
  });
});
```

```html
<nav class="clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li class="navTab marginRight">
            <a><span class="iconFont">v</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>sssss</a></li>
                <li><a>ads</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navTab marginRight">
            <a><span class="iconFont">v</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>hhhh</a></li>
                <li><a>weq</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="navTab">
            <a><span class="iconFont">v</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>ac</a></li>
                <li><a>sadfs</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

yet i haven't apply your css you can decorate as per your customized styles

here is the demo working code

[Demo working code](https://jsfiddle.net/uk18LbLh/3/)

---

Updated code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('li.navTab ul').hide();  
  $('li.navTab').click(function(){
    debugger;
      if($('li.navTab').is(":visible")){
          $('li.navTab ul').hide();
          $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();  
      }    
  });
});
```

**[Demo running code](https://jsfiddle.net/uk18LbLh/7/)**

Comment: @User1979 please checkout my answer

Comment: thanks, but as i say clicking here the first li will show its content, cllicking another li will show also its content but it doesn't hide the first li content and that what i'm not looking for

Comment: @User1979 here i updated code as you want please check out the updated one it's your solution

Comment: @User1979 Still it need to work on styles that would be effective then

Answer (score 0):

`toggleClass()` method may help you.

Comment: using toggleClass() will do the work, but clicking a second tab will shaw its content but dont hide the first tab content